# How do I access unlocked weapons in Dead Cells?

Tags: dead-cells

I found a weapon blueprint and invested cells at the collector until it became "unlocked". A copy of the weapon dropped just then - great! But how can I access that weapon in my next run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you have unlocked the weapon by spending 10 cells, and getting it right there, it starts to spawn randomly in the dungeon.
It can also be a starting weapon, if you have unlocked the randomization for those.
As quite a lot in this game, and typical for a rogue-lite, much of the game is randomised.

Comment: This is pretty standard for this sort of game.  Enter the Gungeon uses an identical system, while Binding of Isaac uses an identical spawn system but a different unlock system.

Comment: It also shows up in stores, and there's upgrades you can buy where you start the game with a random weapon/bow/shield instead of the basic three.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a blueprint, you must turn them in at the end of the level in order to begin unlocking the item.

Once the blueprint is unlocked, you may spend cells to permanently unlock the item.